# BSOD on Windows 7 64 bit. Can someone diagnose this?

Tags: windows-7, windows, troubleshooting, bsod, minidumps

I recently reinstalled windows on my pc in hope this would fix my BSOD problem, it hasn't and has recently crashed again, I was wondering if anyone could help me troubleshoot this and find out what's wrong?

I have uploaded the minidump file here : http://dl.dropbox.com/u/33970527/021412-51605-01.dmp

I have also uploaded a screenshot of the BSOD here: [image]

and the debug info using WhoCrashed:

> Whocrashed info
>
> Crash dump directory: C:\Windows\Minidump
>
> Crash dumps are enabled on your computer.
>
> On Tue 14/02/2012 15:58:35 GMT your computer crashed crash dump file:
>   C:\Windows\Minidump\021412-51605-01.dmp This was probably caused by
>   the following module: ntoskrnl.exe (nt+0x705C0)  Bugcheck code: 0xD1
>   (0xCF434084, 0x2, 0x0, 0xFFFFF88004C9E4B7) Error:
>   DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL file path:
>   C:\Windows\system32\ntoskrnl.exe product: Microsoft® Windows®
>   Operating System company: Microsoft Corporation description: NT Kernel
>   & System Bug check description: This indicates that a kernel-mode
>   driver attempted to access pageable memory at a process IRQL that was
>   too high. This appears to be a typical software driver bug and is not
>   likely to be caused by a hardware problem.  The crash took place in
>   the Windows kernel. Possibly this problem is caused by another driver
>   which cannot be identified at this time.
>
> On Tue 14/02/2012 15:58:35 GMT your computer crashed crash dump file:
>   C:\Windows\memory.dmp This was probably caused by the following
>   module: usbohci.sys (usbohci+0x24B7)  Bugcheck code: 0xD1 (0xCF434084,
>   0x2, 0x0, 0xFFFFF88004C9E4B7) Error: DRIVER_IRQL_NOT_LESS_OR_EQUAL
>   file path: C:\Windows\system32\drivers\usbohci.sys product: Microsoft®
>   Windows® Operating System company: Microsoft Corporation description:
>   OHCI USB Miniport Driver Bug check description: This indicates that a
>   kernel-mode driver attempted to access pageable memory at a process
>   IRQL that was too high. This appears to be a typical software driver
>   bug and is not likely to be caused by a hardware problem.  The crash
>   took place in a standard Microsoft module. Your system configuration
>   may be incorrect. Possibly this problem is caused by another driver on
>   your system which cannot be identified at this time.
>
> ________________________________________ Conclusion
>
> ---
>
> 2 crash dumps have been found and analyzed.  Read the topic general
>   suggestions for troubleshooting system crashes for more information.
>
> Note that it's not always possible to state with certainty whether a
>   reported driver is actually responsible for crashing your system or
>   that the root cause is in another module. Nonetheless it's suggested
>   you look for updates for the products that these drivers belong to and
>   regularly visit Windows update or enable automatic updates for
>   Windows. In case a piece of malfunctioning hardware is causing
>   trouble, a search with Google on the bug check errors together with
>   the model name and brand of your computer may help you investigate
>   this further.

I have no idea what could be causing this and it appears to be happening at random. I was hoping someone could help me out. I can upload any other info you need.

My system is custom built from pcspecialist and I've had the hardware checked recently, however that doesn't completely rule that out as the cause of the problem. also I have very few programs installed at the moment but that doesn't completely rule out a recently installed programmes.

Comment: UPDATE: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/33970527/Crash%20dump%20directory.docx another updated crash report that been debugged after another crash, with the same problem files, but different problems, i have also already updated my mainboard drivers and this still happened

Answer (score 3):

As shown in the screenshot, `usbohci.sys` is the driver that caused the BSOD. A quick web search reveals that as the `Microsoft USB Open Host Controller Miniport Driver`.

So:

1. make sure you have the latest drivers installed that your mainboard
   manufacturer has issued.
2. check all devices, that are connected via USB, for defects.

Comment: ive updated my mainboard drivers to the latest ones, hopefully this will solve the problem, i will also check for defects in any usb devices. thanks

Comment: a day after updating my drivers it crashed again, there is a new updated reoprt above, if you have any other suggestions that would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Did you check your RAM like MadBoy suggested? If there are always different *reasons* for the BSOD, then it is more likely that memory or another central part is defective.

Comment: 3. Check to be sure your motherboard has the latest "BIOS" (more correctly called firmware) installed. Aside from that... usbohci.sys is part of a very large and complex "stack" of drivers and it is entirely possible for one driver in the stack to corrupt things such that usbohci.sys crashes.  But we have a saying in kernel mode driver-land: _The victim is not always the culprit._ usbohci.sys is installed in a huge number of Windows systems so it's pretty unlikely that the problem lies in it. Instead, look at the drivers for other USB devices that were active at the time of the crash.

Answer (score 0):

Have you confirmed you have the correct drivers for all hardware?  Video cards can be a challenge as it may be an ATI chipset but made by say Dell.  Even though it is an ATI chipset, you should only get Dell drivers.  This is common so be sure when you get these drivers, they are by the actuall manufacturer.

Comment: the drivers i use are the ones supllied with the pc and the graphics card? i assumed they were all correct? how would i go about checking this?

my graphics card is a ati radeon card if that helps...

Answer (score 0):

Please run [Ultimate Boot CD](http://www.ultimatebootcd.com/) and check your ram, hard drive and other peripherals for problems with hardware. Then start diagnosing further with driver issues. You should have optimal drivers for your motherboard, graphic card (not always newest is the best and as Dave M suggests having drivers from manufacturer of computer is sometimes preferred over overall drivers. If everything else works then you can "try" using newest ones.